# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5B42403

Tags: java, mysql

I've searched around on a lot of forums but have yet to find an answer to my issue. I've read quite a few topics from people having the same issue as me here on this site but most of them were using applets and servlets and I couldn't see what I was doing wrong compared to them.

Anyways, on to my issue. I've recently just taken up learning MySQL, so if you see anything horrendous, forgive me. I'm trying to take a serializable object, and write it to a table in MySQL. From the research I did, I figured out that I needed to use BLOB as the field and that I would need to write to it using a byte[]. Writing works fine, no issues, but when I try to read it, I get the above error.

My write method:

```
    public void addColonist(String p, Colonist c) {
        // Serializing the Colonist
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteObject = null;

        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            out.writeObject(c);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            baos.flush();

            byteObject = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Adding it to MySQL
        sql.query("INSERT INTO colonistdb (`player`, `colonist`) VALUES('" + p + "', '" + byteObject + "')");
    }
```

And my read/find method:

```
    public Colonist getColonist(String p) {
        // Getting the object from MySQL
        ResultSet rs = sql.query("SELECT `colonist` FROM colonistdb WHERE `player` = '" + p + "'");
        byte[] byteObject = null;
        try {
            if (rs.first()) {
                byteObject = (byte[]) rs.getObject("colonist");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        return null;
        }

        if (byteObject == null) {
            System.out.println("byteObject is null");
            return null;
        }

        // Deserializing it for use
        ByteArrayInputStream bais;
        Colonist colonist = null;

        try {
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteObject);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            colonist = (Colonist) in.readObject();

            in.close();
            bais.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Colonist successfully retrived");

        return colonist;
    }
```

From what I've read on a bunch of other questions and posts, I might need to make an ObjectOutputStream in my read method, but I tried that to no avail...

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I've answered your question, but you shouldn't be storing your objects in binary format in the database though. Anytime you make a modifications to your object like adding or deleting a filed, all the old ones stored in the database won't be able to be read correctly. Also you can't do any queries like only select colonists that have a name starting with 'rich'. Ideally each class you wan't to persist should have it's own table in the database.

Comment: Well, this is actually a plugin for a minecraft server I "work" for. It's not being used so the adding/deleting fields issue isn't really a problem right now. I could always make an updater for old file though could I not?

Comment: @Hiro2k That is not correct. Adding or deleting fields does not break compatibility under serialization. This is discussed extensively in the Object Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Spcification.

Comment: Adding on to this ... How would updating a pre-existing column work? Could I do `UPDATE colonistdb SET colonist = " + byteObject + " WHERE player = " + c.getName()`

Comment: No you have to use the prepared statement again, just like in the answer. You cannot concatenate the byteObject array to a string.

Comment: That's what I tried but it didn't work :/


`PreparedStatement stmt = sql.prepare("REPLACE colonistdb (player, colonist) VALUES (?, ?)");

try {
    stmt.setString(1, c.getName());
    stmt.setBytes(2, byteObject)
    stmt.execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`

That was my latest attempt but no go, all it does is save another column with the same name, and the new data.         Also, sorry about the terrible formatting here :/ I can't figure out how to get line breaks in the comments

Comment: Ah! Nevermind I got it :) Used an UPDATE instead of REPLACE and it worked fine :D Thank you @Hiro2k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting the data wrong. You need to use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to make it work.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = sql.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO colonistdb (`player`, `colonist`) VALUES(?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1, p);
pstmt.setBytes(2, byteObject);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```